# Role of "en" in "Il en pendait dans toute la maison"

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, en

I'm reading ***[La Fuite de Monsieur Monde](http://www.toutsimenon.com/oeuvre/tout-simenon/fiche-livre/17-La-fuite-de-Monsieur-Monde_3917)*** by Georges Simenon. It contains this passage:

> S'il avait osé, il aurait dit:
>   – Un complet de tout le monde.
>   Il en pendait dans toute la maison.

I've understood that the sort of suit he wanted was on display throughout the shop. But I'm puzzled by the ***en***.

Could someone please explain what it expresses?

Comment: From what I can [tell](https://books.google.com/books?id=xmjxAAAAMAAJ&q=%22Un+complet+de+tout+le+monde.+Il+en+pendait+dans+toute+la+maison.%22&dq=%22Un+complet+de+tout+le+monde.+Il+en+pendait+dans+toute+la+maison.%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizi6iU8J7KAhWLKx4KHXo1BX8Q6AEIGzAA), the text is not formatted like so and the sentence does not end with _maison_ and a period...

Comment: @Legomononc'bléd'Ingres: You're right. Sorry to have confused you. I typed 3 lines but my formatting was overridden.The unexpressed speech ended with "monde", and the narrative resumed with "Il". That last sentence ended with "maison" and a period.

Comment: @Legomononc'bléd'Ingres: You're right. I'm un peu embarrassed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a conjunction of 2 constructions :

**An impersonal form: Il + verb (about events) + real subject**

> Il pendait des complets dans toute la maison = Des complets pendaient
>   dans toute la maison.
>
> Il pleuvait des trombes d'eau = Des trombes d'eau pleuvaient.

**Pronoun personal *en* = replaces indefinite noun, or COI preceded by *de***

> Je voyais des complets = J'en voyais.
>
> Je parlais de ces choses = J'en parlais.
>
> Je viens de Paris = J'en viens.

like *y* is for COI preceded by *à*:

> Je pense à ça = J'y pense.
>
> J'arrive à Paris = J'y arrive.

Comment: Yes it was the impersonal use of "il" that led me astray. I can see now that, in my terms, it is being used as a placeholder for the true subject. And while I'm familiar with this usage with verbs such as avoir, être and falloir, I hadn't realised that its application was wider. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

***en*** replaces/refers to simply ***un complet***.

> Il ***en*** pendait dans toute la maison  ⇔ Il pendait ***un complet*** dans
>   toute la maison

By ⇔ I mean equivalence of the 2 sentences.

[Remember:](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/contenu/20/grammaire/573.html)

> Le pronom en remplace un nom introduit par de ou par un article
>   partitif ou indéfini qui expriment une quantité indéfinie.

Comment: Thank you. As I've mentioned to Guillaume, it was the use of "il" as a placeholder for the true subject which confused me.